# Why does the seven segment display have decimal point at the right?

Tags: 7segmentdisplay

All the seven segment displays I’ve seen so far have their decimal point to the right of the main digit. Why is this so? A decimal point to the left will be able to represent more possible combinations of numbers.

A single digit display with a decimal point on the left can represent nine more possible numbers (\$ .1,\ \ldots ,\  .9 \$) than the common display with decimal point at the right.

**Edit:** Why also do the digits lean towards right?

Comment: So you can put a decimal point to the right of your number wherever it is.

Comment: You say "like in a single digit display" then give an example with 2 digits: (0.1,....) Having the leading zero improves readability, so that's one reason to use 2 digits with a decimal on the right instead of a single digit with the decimal on the left.

Comment: FYI I've seen 7 segments with decimal points on both the right *and* the left, but not just the left.

Comment: @JohnD I’ve edited now. Instead of readability, is there any other reason?

Comment: Perhaps because there's room for the DP at the bottom right and none at the bottom left.

Comment: @mike65535 - I think you may have it. I don't see there being a more concise reason. You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @jsotola - OP already showed how. Do you have reasoning to say otherwise? If you have the DP on the right, you can only show 0 through 9. If you have the DP on the left, you can also show (imply) 0.1 through 0.9

Comment: @mike65535 That’s plausible!

Comment: many displays lean the digits right, to give an italic effect. That leaves more room bottom right than left.

Comment: @Neil_UK But now, why are they generally oblique?

Comment: @Atom - Maybe it was to leave room for the decimal point :)

Comment: I think most of the original applications typically used decimals on the right or not all:  Digital clocks had a colon rather than a decimal, multimeters usually had the leftmost half-digit and decimal to the right, multimeters and calculators had the leading zero for readability with decimal to the right.  As @Bort pointed out, there have been 7 segments with the decimal available on both sides, but the vast majority were on the right.  Mostly about the market rather than any technical reason I think.

Comment: @Bort, my bad ... I must be dyslexic today

Comment: A decimal point to the right can also be used as a trailing period.  e.g.:`"HOLd 5AFE."`

Comment: wasn't the dot meant to be flashed e.g. for clocks? To show something is "active"? Nothing more?

Comment: @Gizmo - Then what would its name "DP" stand for if not Decimal Point?

Comment: Writing decimal fractions between 0 and 1 without a leasing zero is lousy human factors.  Without a leading zero, the decimal point is easy to miss.  [Only school kids in the US would write a decimal fraction without a leading zero.  Literature uses leading zeros.  European schools teach to write leading zeros.]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think [mike65535](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/119874/mike65535) is probably correct, more-or-less.

Of course the argument that there's room on the right of the digit and not the left only makes sense if the digit is *slanted* to the right. There's some discussion of that [over here](https://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/why-are-7-segment-displays-slanted.16285/). What's missing from that discussion is that a slight rightward slant gives characters that are *slightly* more similar to handwriting.

The idea that one can get another power-of-ten out of a given display by putting the point on the left makes sense, but I don't think it would be a good design decision unless you were already constrained to just one or two digits.

A "bare" decimal (without the leading zero) isn't as easy to read, is more likely to be mis-read, and will always be at the low end of the displayable range. Even if we did have the decimal point on the left, it would still almost always be the rigth decision to pay the cost & space for another display digit.

Comment: >>A "bare" decimal (without the leading zero).  YES!  We engineers were all taught to never write a value without the leading zero for the very reason you cite.

Comment: and non-engineering users might not know that .25 is 0.25 and all sorts of bad things happen. Also, I saw applications where a seven segment display's DP is blinking to indicate operation or progress...

Comment: Also, if the whole display has to cover that large of a range, it would probably be easier, more efficient and more maintainable to just introduce scientific notation, thus making the leftmost dot a moot point (pun not intended).

Answer (score 28):

[image]

*Figure 1. Vertical display. [Source](https://everydayitct.weebly.com/display-module.html).*

[image]

*Figure 2. Slanted display. [Source](https://everydayitct.weebly.com/display-module.html).*

Reasons for slant:

- '7' in particular, '4' to a lesser extent and perhaps '2', '3', '5', '6' and '9' all appear more natural and resemble print typeface numerals more closely. The others look like italics which we are used to reading and the eye seems to accommodate this quite comfortably.

Reasons for decimal on the right:

- There's more room there due to the slant. (See above.)
- Decimal numbers < 1 should always be written with a leading zero. The leading zero is a visual clue that a decimal is being displayed even if the observer doesn't notice it.

Personally, I find 'square' displays a little disconcerting.

**Edit by Michael Karas**

The idea to rotate one seven segment display 180° to create a colon for a clock, as posed in the comments, is just not a usable solution in my estimation. I have edited this here to be able to show why.

[image]

Comment: Have you ever read Blindsight by Peter Watts?

Comment: Nope, and there's no mention of "segment" in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blindsight_(Watts_novel)) on the book.

Comment: I'm referring your finding orthogonal things disconcerting.

Comment: Also if you rotate some segments 180° you can make a colon which works nicely for a clock display.

Comment: @DKNguyen the Wikipedia article doesn't mention the vampires' orthogonal vulnerability at all, unfortunately.  [TVTropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/Blindsight) mentions it though: "Vampires, because of their unique spatial reasoning, get seizures when they see too many right angles. It gave rise to the myth that they're vulnerable to crosses, but the truth is they short out if they see something as simple as a window pane or a building with a square footprint. They largely went extinct after the invention of architecture in early human history."

Comment: @Transistor I hope there were an option to accept two answers!

Comment: @ratchetfreak - The idea to rotate a 7-seg display 180° to create a "colon" for a clock looks pretty unusual in my perception. I have added a picture to Transistor's excellent answer to illustrate this point.

Comment: @MichaelKaras I've seen it done that way a number of times on actual products that have a clock. It's just an italic colon.

Comment: @MichaelKaras when I've seen this done, the decimal is usually at/above the baseline on the display, rather than below as portrayed; it looks much more natural this way. (see [this Wikipedia image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ad/Seven_segment_02_Pengo.jpg))

Answer (score 2):

Punctuation ,as a typesetting and -writing tradition ,is always placed immediately *after* a character ,not before .We are just used to see it that way .Note that there are also alphanumeric displays ,not just numeric ones .

Comment: And spaces are placed after the punctuation not before, too.

Comment: I assume it was written that way to emphasise the point.

Answer (score 1):

I have an hob where each hot plate uses a single digit. The dot is used to indicate `.5` or "point something". I think that range is somewhat more useful than one half in `[0..1]` and the other in `[1..9]`.

To elaborate more on this, because not everyone seems to get my point:

If you see that use case valid (as I think you should because its an actual product) the assumption that the dot on the left would increase the number of possible values (as done in the question) is not correct. With the dot on the left you get:

(.0), 0 ,.1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

With the dot on the right:

0, 0., 1, 1., 2, 2., 3, 3., 4, 4., 5, 5., 6, 6., 7, 7., 8, 8., 9, 9.

So you have the same amount of different states / numbers, but with the latter range the numbers are evenly spaced, while the first range is split between two resolutions: `.1` and `1`.

Comment: The numbers go in order "0", "0.", "1", "1.", "2", "2." etc

Comment: I'm not completely sure what *"one half in [0..1] and the other in [1..9]."* means. But seems more like a comment than an answer. Maybe I just don't understand.

Comment: My hob at home does this. 1.5 is represented by `1.`

Comment: @Bort I think he means that of the 20 numbers that can be displayed with one of 10 digits and a dot, putting the dot to the left gives you 10 numbers between 0 and 1 (with the dot showing) and 10 numbers between 1 and 9 (without the dot). That isn't strictly true as "0" and ".0" are the same number, but I think that's the gist. By contrast, putting the dot to the right to mean ".5" gives 20 numbers equally spaced between 0 and 9.5.